# flutter not playing audio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

//ignore this line cuz you are a programmer//
i am new to flutter and i made this Xylophone app, everything is fine, there is no error at all. But the sounds are not playing in the emulator, can you guys figure out the problem in here.

the pubspec.yaml is also good to go. no problems there.

flutter:
uses-material-design: true

assets:
- assets/

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   home: XyloPhone(),
 ));
}

class XyloPhone extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _XyloPhoneState createState() => _XyloPhoneState();
}

class _XyloPhoneState extends State<XyloPhone> {
 final _controller1 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/1.mp3');
 final _controller2 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/2.mp3');
 final _controller3 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/3.mp3');
 final _controller4 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/4.mp3');
 final _controller5 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/5.mp3');
 final _controller6 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/6.mp3');
 final _controller7 = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/7.mp3');

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
         child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
             //First One
             SizedBox(
               height: 60.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.white,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                       topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                       topLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller1.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 230,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.green[700],
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             //Second One
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller2.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 250,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.blue[800],
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             //third one
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller3.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 270,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.amber,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             //forth one
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller4.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 290,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.orange[800],
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             //fifth one
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller5.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 310,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.purple,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             //sixth 0ne
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller6.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 330,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.red[700],
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             //seventh one
             InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 _controller7.play();
               },
               child: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 400,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.teal,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 60.0,
               width: 30.0,
               child: Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.white,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                       bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                       bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: please post the whole pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Add `_controller.setVolume(1.0);` to your controllers.